# Facebook SDK edge.create is deprecated. Any alternative?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

[image]

---

`edge.create` and `edge.remove` **JS SDK Events** are deprecated. Is there any alternative to allows users to subscribe to the like happening event (fired when the like action is completed)? I've not found any webhooks to replace the callback function I used before deprecation:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // like clicked
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> edge.create and edge.remove JS SDK Events: These Events will no longer
>   be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be
>   notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

For more information 
[Facebook Offical](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/)